# Iterate over json array in Go to extract values

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have the following in my json array (conf.json file).

```
{
  "Repos": [
      "a",
      "b",
      "c"
  ]
}
```

I am attempting to read this json and then iterate over it but get stuck.  I am very new to go (and to programming) so I am having a hard time understanding what is happening here.

```
import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

type Configuration struct {
    Repos []string
}

func read_config() {
    file, _ := os.Open("conf.json")
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(file)
    configuration := Configuration{}
    err := decoder.Decode(&configuration)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
    }

    fmt.Println(configuration.Repos)
}
```

So far this is as far as I have been able to get.  This will print out the values okay, `[a, b, c]`.

What I would like to do is be able to iterate over the array and split out each value individually but have not had any luck at doing this.  Am I taking the wrong approach to this?  Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with JSON. You should just have asked how to iterate over a slice. Where you got the slice from doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mean something like this:

```
for _, repo := range configuration.Repos {
    fmt.Println(repo)
}
```

Note that the code in your example should not work with the JSON that you have given. There is no mapping between `value` and `Repos`. You either have posted incorrect JSON or omitted a tag on the `Configuration` struct to map it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Everything worked fine, it's just your printing that is not doing what you expect. Since Repos is an array you'll have to iterate it to print each value individually. Try something like this;

```
for _, repo := range configuration.Repos {
    fmt.Println(repo)
}
```